# Is $|f(y_1)-f(y_2)|\leqslant||f||||y_1-y_2||$ true in a Banach space?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

I have used during a functional analasys course the following identity:

> Consider f as a linear functional on a given infinite-dimensional normed space $Y$, then: $|f(y_1)-f(y_2)|\leqslant||f||||y_1-y_2||$.

If we had admitted that Y was an Hilbert space it is known by Riesz theorem there exists a unique element $u\in Y$ such that $f(x)=\langle x, u\rangle$.
Applying Cauchy inequality we get:
So $\langle x,u\rangle\leqslant ||u|||x||\implies ||f||=u$

**Question**: However if we are dealing with a Banach space where the inner product is not defined how would the inequality $|f(y_1)-f(y_2)|\leqslant||f||||y_1-y_2||$ hold?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just check the definition of $\Vert f \Vert$. It easily follows from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X$ be a Banach space (more generally a normed space) and $\,f: X\to\mathbb R$ a linear functional.

$f$ is said to be *bounded* (equivalently *continuous*) if and only if there exists an $M\ge 0$, such that
$$
|\,f(x)|\le M\|x\|,\quad\text{for all $x\in X$.} \tag{1}
$$
The least $M$ for which $(1)$ holds is defined to be the norm of $f$, i.e.,
$$
\|\,f\|=\sup_{x\ne 0}\frac{|\,f(x)|}{\|x\|}.
$$
Note that $(1)$ implies that
$$
|\,f(x)-f(y)|\le M\|x-y\|,
$$
for all $x,y\in X$.